# Always have to type "?fdsa=5" after website URL for it to load properly

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I am working on a WordPress website and have done some changes in the past to its PHP code, But whenever I open the website it is all messed up.

-Only after I type "?*somegibberish*=5" (example ?fdsa=5) after its URL and reload the website does it go back to normal

> I have tried clearing all kinds of cache still doesn't help

Comment: Disable the caching plugins you're using + the ones that combines and minifies the CSS and JS

Comment: And check your permalinks and rewrite rules in .htaccess.